# Are there math libs for F#?

Tags: math, f#

As far as I known, there are are numpy and scipy for python.

Are there similar libs for F#?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3227647/open-source-math-library-for-f

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are good commercial math libraries in .Net (you can use google to find them).

For free ones, [Math.Net](http://www.mathdotnet.com/) is the best available. However, its development has been paused for a long time.

Anyway, the .Net libraries usually have C# friendly interface. You need to do a wrapper in F# to use them conveniently.

I use [F# Math Providers](http://fdatamining.blogspot.com/2010/03/matrix-and-linear-algebra-in-f-part-ii.html), which is a PInovke wrapper to LAPACK. You can use either the [free netlib lapack implementation](http://fdatamining.blogspot.com/2010/03/compiling-lapack-for-net-usage.html) or INTEL MKL. The inner part of this wrapper is analyzed [here](http://fdatamining.blogspot.com/2010/08/reading-f-projects-part-iii-f-math.html).

For more reference, I have written an [F# matrix series](http://fdatamining.blogspot.com/2010/04/matrix-and-linear-algebra-in-f-part-v.html) in my blog.

Answer (score 2):

For open source libraries, see [Math.NET](http://numerics.mathdotnet.com/) (the major .NET open source math initiative), and [F# MathProvider](http://mathprovider.codeplex.com/) (a wrapper for LAPACK that used to be part of the F# power pack).

For 3rd part libraries, see [NAG](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsyme/archive/2010/11/13/f-math-nag-library-for-net-with-f-support.aspx), [Extreme Optimization](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsyme/archive/2010/12/02/f-math-extreme-optimization-4-0-released-50-quick-start-samples-in-f.aspx) and [NMath](http://www.centerspace.net/products/overview/).